# What materials can be used to prevent the settling of particles in the ceramic slurry?

Tags: physical-chemistry, home-experiment, popular-science

How can we avoid the Settle particles in the ceramic slurry?
What materials can be used for this purpose?

Comment: Settling over what time scales? What is the characteristic size and density of your ceramic particles? What constraints are there on the allowable liquids that can be mixed with the ceramic particles (e.g., toxicity, flammability, temperature range, etc.)? You need to provide a lot more details about what this question is all about.

Comment: Look up 'anti flocculant' and go from there...

Comment: So they prevent flakes forming by  charging the surface of suspended particles in the slurry.
Adding anti-flocculants is an established industrial process that doubtless has received significant attention; you may be lucky, but round here you are more likely to get help on basic Physics. Have you posted on chemistry?
Does agitation help? This could be achieved with an electromagnetic field?

Answer (score 1):

There are two strategies, and which is best depends on the detail of your system. The strategies are broadly:

1. reduce the rate of particle settling
2. flocculate the suspension

Generally speaking option (1) is only good for short term storage and only if you can find a suitably non-Newtonian thickening agent with a high low shear viscosity but low high shear viscosity. If you try to use a Newtonian fluid then making it viscous enough to retard settling can make it too think to pump easily. An additional problem with this approach is that if settling does occur you'll get a close packed dilatant sediment that is exceedingly difficult to redisperse.

The approach I've generally seen used is option (2). If your slurry has a high volume fraction of the solid then you can flocculate it by adding some suitable destabilising compound. When the suspended particles flocculate they knit together to form a porous network that is strong enough to support its own weight:

[image: Flocculate]

([Image from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_aggregation))

Your aim is to achieve a structure like the one on the right where the network of flocculated particles keeps the suspension from settling. There are several advantages to this approach:

- it usually requires only low concentrations of additive to cause the flocculation
- if settling does occur you get a loose and easily redipersed sediment
- the flocculate breaks down and thins at even low shear rates so it is easy to pump

The flocculation mechanism will depend on our material. Most ceramics are negatively charged in aqueous suspension so you'd probably find a cationic surfactant works well. You'll have to try it and see.

As it happens [I have a patent on exactly this type of stabilisation](https://www.google.com/patents/EP0464920A2?cl=en) but using depletion flocculation by a non-adsorbing polymer. However I'm not sure I'd recommend using this approach unless nothing else works.